# Mac Calendar add shared calendar for email account with 2 letter email address

Tags: mac, calendar, ical, exchange

One of the meeting rooms at our new offices has a short email address (tv@ourdomain.com).

The calendar sharing function only works on a search for email addresses (I can't type in an address manually) but the search only starts after the 3rd character *before* the @ symbol (and stops after the @ symbol).

Is there any way around this? Or any way to add the address manually? On adding it manually it says that it can't be found (although sending an email in mac mail finds the address easily and allows sending).

I'm using Mac Mail and Calendar with Microsoft Exchange accounts.

Many thanks

Comment: Add the emailaddress as contact, does that help?

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Comment: You have Office 2011 by any chance?

Comment: try inserting global symbols before like ?tv, or space tv

Comment: @Buscar웃 that worked! I tried >tv (mistyped ?tv) which seemed to work fine and brought up the email address from the global contacts. Please add as an answer and I'll mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes using wild (global) characters in a search field to fill in the space helps.

Try using

?tv

or space tv

or !tv

or >tv

try any of those :)